# Google Maps API not returning localized results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Map API is not returning me localized results to my region.
In my HTML header, I am calling `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MYAPIKEY>&sensor=false&region=SG" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Is there anything I need to specify other than the region parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "localization" do you mean the language of your map or the biasing of search results (like London in Enland vs. London in Canada)?

The **language** of the map is automatically adapted to the language settings of the visitor's browser. If you want to force it to a specific language, you can use the language parameter in the script tag's src attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=pt-BR">
```

For the **biasing** you can use the region parameter as you did. This will NOT change the language of the map.

The above parameters are valid for Google Maps API v3 only.
If you use API v2 you have to use the hl parameter for the language setting and AFAIK a region biasing is not available in v2.

**EDIT:**

To see the result of **biasing** please compare the output of the following two requests:

Search for *Woodland*, biased for Singapore
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=woodlands&sensor=false&region=sg

Search for *Woodland*, biased for USA
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=woodlands&sensor=false&region=us

Comment: Say if I do a search for "woodlands", Google returns me location results from the UK, instead of the ones in SG.

Comment: Right now I got to do silly massaging behind the input textbox, in order to get the right results.

Comment: Your region biasing works perfectly for me. See the examples in my edit above. Could it be that there is an error in the parameter chain of the src attribute of your script tag? This could result in paramaters towards the end of the chain being ignored (e.g. the region paramater at the very end).

Comment: No idea why. Thanks for reply. I am calling the API from inside DirectionService though. Likewise, I am able to call it via a json. Following works for me also http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=woodlands&destination=jalan%kasau&sensor=false&region=sg